# Is my PC suitable in 64 Bit operating system?

Tags: graphics-card

System profile of my home PC:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L
- Pentium Dual Core CPU E5300 @2.6 GHz
- 2 GB RAM

Will it support 64-bit operating system?
If yes then please tell me what type of graphics card I can use in this PC.

Comment: Your proc supports 64bit instructions so you can run 64bit OS on it if you want. You can run any video card that your motherboard supports.

Comment: shinjijai is correct, but I would definitely add more RAM to that system. At 2GB, it might be doing a lot of swapping to virtual memory if you try to start opening too many programs.

Comment: What does a graphics card have to do with installing a 64-bit operating system?

Answer (score 4):

Whilst you may be ablto to run 64bit with that motherboard, the real question is *should you*.

Unless you plan to increase your RAM beyond 4GB, it is unlikely that you will see any gains. Indeed, it might even run slightly slower (though probably not really noticeably).

Not only does running a 64bit OS have additional overheads due to extended memory addressing, you also start to get 32/64bit application inconsistencies and clashes.

Quite honestly, there is no gain at all for running 64bit Windows unless you are putting in >4GB of RAM or need a **humongously** large hard drive or files.

Comment: Note that 64 bit provides additional general-purpose registers to the CPU which can actually cause it to access RAM less and this can result in speed increases, even if 64-bit pointers are needed to access memory.

Comment: Ah, good call @ultrasawblade. Any stats on how much difference this makes? I guess it will be down to how applications are written? My own experience bears out my response though.

Comment: Interesting. Are there no disadvantages at all then(Julian and @ultrasawblade  and others) ?

Comment: As mentioned, there are no real issues to using Win 32bit until you hit the size limits - normally memory since out of 4GB you can't access it all directly. Well written 64bit applications WILL run faster but will you notice? Generally, memory makes the biggest difference to speed on Windows if you have an i5 or similar processor (for general use - a bit different for games and other intensive graphic apps).